# Expanding a link to the div containing it

Tags: html, css

I have got this button:

```css
.menu-main-window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .tlm-options {
    display: table;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .menu-text {
    display: none;
}
.tlm-options {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    color: #0089c8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div {
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0089c8;
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div:last-child div {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tlm-options div div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tlm-options div div a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tlm-options div div a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
.tlm-options div:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: NewJuneBold;
}
.menu-btn {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid White;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.menu-btn:hover {
    border: 3px solid #0089c8;
    /* Azul Ascendi */
    transition: border 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn:hover .menu-text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-item-div-top {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-window">
    <div class="menu-item-div-top">
        <div class="menu-btn btn-tlm" style="background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png'); background-size: cover;">
            <div class="menu-text">MENU</div>
            <div class="tlm-options">
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option1</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option2</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option3</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option4</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the 4 options to be links when hovering the area of the div, not only hovering the text. How can I achieve it?

Comment: put the :hover on the div itself. e.g. `div:hover a { text-decoration: underline }` but you can't make the div clickable that way. the `<a>` would have to be put inside the div so it contains ALL of the div's content. e.g. `<div><a ..>blahblahblah</a></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your question solution is Below :-

-- Just Remove your table-cell div

-- Make your anchor "A" as table-cell, and it working fine. The whole area is clickable now.

```
.menu-main-window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .tlm-options {
    display: table;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .menu-text {
    display: none;
}
.tlm-options {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    color: #0089c8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div {
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0089c8;
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div:last-child a {
    border-bottom: none;
}    
.tlm-options div a {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;        
    vertical-align: middle
}
.tlm-options div a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tlm-options div a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
.tlm-options div:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: NewJuneBold;
}
.menu-btn {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid White;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.menu-btn:hover {
    border: 3px solid #0089c8;
    /* Azul Ascendi */
    transition: border 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn:hover .menu-text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-item-div-top {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}


<div class="menu-main-window">
    <div class="menu-item-div-top">
        <div class="menu-btn btn-tlm" style="background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png'); background-size: cover;">
            <div class="menu-text">MENU</div>
            <div class="tlm-options">
                <div>
                    <a href="../somewhere">Option1</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="../somewhere">Option2</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="../somewhere">Option3</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="../somewhere">Option4</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 100% height and width, and a line height that measures the height of the direct parent.

```css
.tlm-options div > a {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     line-height: 100px; /* Same as the height of .tlm-options div div */
 }

.menu-main-window {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .tlm-options {
    display: table;
}
.btn-tlm:hover .menu-text {
    display: none;
}
.tlm-options {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    color: #0089c8;
    border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div {
    display: table-row;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0089c8;
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.tlm-options div:last-child div {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.tlm-options div div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px
}
.tlm-options div div a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tlm-options div div a:visited {
    color: inherit;
}
.tlm-options div:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-family: NewJuneBold;
}
.menu-btn {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid White;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: all 100ms linear;
}
.menu-btn:hover {
    border: 3px solid #0089c8;
    /* Azul Ascendi */
    transition: border 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn:hover .menu-text {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    color: black;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
.menu-item-div-top {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-main-window">
    <div class="menu-item-div-top">
        <div class="menu-btn btn-tlm" style="background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/512/Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png'); background-size: cover;">
            <div class="menu-text">MENU</div>
            <div class="tlm-options">
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option1</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option2</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option3</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div> <a href="../somewhere">Option4</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[See the full display here on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92u0t0zq/)**

Comment: The text isn't vertically centered this way

Comment: To get the vertical align right, you need a fixed height for .tlm-options div div. That way you won't be needing padding to get it centered(vertically) properly. Check the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Switch between the `<a>` and the `<div>`
instead of:

```
<div> <a href="../somewhere">Option4</a>

                    </div>
```

write:

```
<a href="../somewhere"><div> Option4</div></a>
```

and change the CSS accordingly

Comment: This solution - although it works great - creates invalid code though. Inline elements shall never contain block elements!

Comment: True, I think you could just make expand the link with css though.
Then maybe you don't need the div?

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the links to inline-block or block elements and give them 100% height and width.

```
.tlm-options div > div > a {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the links block-level:

`.tlm-options a {
    display: block;
}`